# Django : Urls with django-activity-streams

Tags: python, django

I have download the django-activity-streams project.

So I did this  :
`pip install django-activity-stream`

After that, I set location of the app 'actstream' (/django-activity-stream/actstream) in my project (same location than my manage.py)

But when I add the activity urls to my urlconf like this :

```
import django
import actstream
from django.contrib.auth.views import login 
from django.contrib import auth
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from actstream.views import *

urlpatterns = [,
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accueil',accueil,name="accueil"),
    url(r'^activity/$', include('actstream.urls')),
]
```

I have this error in my terminal :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f6c6abdc230>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
 res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/bouslim/Projets/projup/projup/urls.py", line 72, in <module>
url(r'^activity/$', include('actstream.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/bouslim/Projets/projup/actstream/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
from actstream import feeds, views
  File "/home/bouslim/Projets/projup/actstream/feeds.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in <module>
class Site(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
"application was loaded. " % (module, name))

RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't
declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in     
INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need have both these conditions met:

- `django.contrib.sites` needs to be an entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting
- Ensure `django.contrib.sites` needs to be present *before* `actstream` in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`. ([More on this here](http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#basic-app-configuration))

If either of these conditions are not met, django could raise the exception you are seeing.

---

The other thing i notice is, in your url patterns,

```
url(r'^activity/$', include('actstream.urls')),
```

should be

```
url(r'^activity/', include('actstream.urls')),
```

The `$` indicates end of pattern, and none of the URLs under `activity/` would be recognized if it is present.

Comment: Ah perfect, it's works ! Thank you very very much ! I saw the warning on "django.contrib.sites" but I have a django version more recent than 1.7 (I have Django 1.9)